# Python Requests : urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: 'Connection aborted.'

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am newbie to python. I am trying to extract data from API's. I tried extracting data in my local using postman and it extracts the data. But when I use python requests I am getting connection aborted error. Can someone please help me in understanding this issue.

Below are the code that I have tried:

```
import requests
from requests import request

url = "https://abcd/smart_general_codes?category=BANK"

payload={}
headers = {
  'TenantId': 'IN0XXX',
  'Accept-Language': 'en_us',
  'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
  'fileType': 'json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Code2:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("main.com")

payload = ''
headers = {
  'powerpayTenantId': 'IN0XXX',
  'Accept-Language': 'en_us',
  'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
  'fileType': 'json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX'
}
conn.request("GET", "abcd/smart_general_codes?category=BANK", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Both using httpclient and requests method throws the below error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login_2.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. In postman the accept language was showing as en_us but updating that to en_US worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a fake user-agent (such as chrome) and your cookies (if needed) in headers like this:

```py
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '<Your cookie>'
}
```

By the way, you can get your cookies by typing `document.cookie` in your browser's developer console.

Comment: Thanks @AgOH for reply. But still the above thing din't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `data=payload`  from the requests and try.